# Get user data only works when MS Form is shared inside organisation

Tags: office365, power-automate, microsoft-forms, ms-forms

My Flow in Power Automate only works when the Microsoft Form is shared inside the organisation because it doesn't get Office 365 user data when shared outside. We work with another company so I need to be able to share it within 2 companies with 2 types of email addresses and still get the needed Office 365 data that we need. Can I change our organisation to 2 organisations somehow? Or is there a way to still collect user data without sharing it inside my organisation?

Comment: Open your Form, click on the Ellipsis on the top-right. and change "Who can fill out this form" to "Anyone can respond"

Comment: A few questions that might be able to help any solution. 1. Are your companies related at all within the Microsoft Infrastructure (tenancies, related 365 groups, etc)? 2. How much of that company will be accessing the form? 3. Do you have a free or a paid Forms account?

Comment: Unfortunately it stops capturing the user info when "Anyone can respond" is turned on. And our Microsoft accounts are managed separately. So the users have to capture all their own info every time they complete a form and they complete more than 10 a day each. To answer your last question, we have business accounts.